# Counting inversions which involves swaps between elements greater than a certain value

Tags: sorting

This is a homework question which I have spent quite a lot of time thinking.

Suppose I've an unsorted array of integers, and a given integer d. The task is to count the number of inversions that involves swaps greater than d.

For example, given an input array (3, 4, 3, 1) and d = 2, the number of such inversions is 1 as only the inversion between 4 and 1 is counted. The other inversions have a difference of less than 2.

Of course, an easy way to count the number of inversions is to iterate though every number of the list, and add the number of elements ahead of that number, which is smaller and the difference is more than d. However, this is a n^2 algorithm. A n \log n algorithm is needed instead.

Another more efficient algorithm is given here, where we perform mergesort on the input array and directly count from there. 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions-subarrays-given-size/

However, I'm having trouble modifying this to get a correct answer.

My approach is something like this:

During the 'merge' step of mergesort, if the first item of the left subarray is smaller, then just add it to the sorted array and continue.

Else, I increment the number of inversions needed with the number of items in the left subarray greater than the first item of the right subarray by d.

Nonetheless, I'm still having trouble getting the correct answer.

Can someone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide code that you have already tried? What is the output/errors of it? Also I can't see any info about programming language that you are using.

Comment: This looks like a NUS CS3230 assignment question. If this is for that assignment, please note that it is against the course policy to ask questions about assignment questions online. Please disregard this if this is not related to that course

Answer (score 0):

During the merging process, if the element of index i of the left sub-array A[i] is greater than the element of index j of the right sub-array A[j], there will be j-i swaps there.

Do a binary search for the smallest element that has a difference greater than the value on the sub-array from A[i...j-1]. Then the number of swaps between elements greater than the value will be j minus the index of this smallest element.